# User registration with email validation php - PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, email

I have email validation problem..Im usiung PHPMailer and when i try to register it says that email was successfuly send on email. but i dont get any new email... so please help me fix the problem..

Error message:

```html
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP s129sm33517920wmf.18 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [193.2.186.194] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 s129sm33517920wmf.18 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 Flushed s129sm33517920wmf.18 - gsmtp 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

and this is the code i use:

```html
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

class USER
{ 

 private $conn;
 
 public function __construct()
 {
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->dbConnection();
  $this->conn = $db;
    }
 
 public function runQuery($sql)
 {
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
  return $stmt;
 }
 
 public function lasdID()
 {
  $stmt = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
  return $stmt;
 }
 
 public function register($uname,$email,$upass,$code)
 {
  try
  {       
   $password = md5($upass);
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userEmail,userPass,tokenCode) 
                                                VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, :active_code)");
   $stmt->bindparam(":user_name",$uname);
   $stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
   $stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
   $stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
   $stmt->execute(); 
   return $stmt;
  }
  catch(PDOException $ex)
  {
   echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
 }
 
 public function login($email,$upass)
 {
  try
  {
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
   $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
   $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   
   if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
   {
    if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
    {
     if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
     {
      $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
      return true;
     }
     else
     {
      header("Location: index.php?error");
      exit;
     }
    }
    else
    {
     header("Location: index.php?inactive");
     exit;
    } 
   }
   else
   {
    header("Location: index.php?error");
    exit;
   }  
  }
  catch(PDOException $ex)
  {
   echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
 }
 
 
 public function is_logged_in()
 {
  if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
  {
   return true;
  }
 }
 
 public function redirect($url)
 {
  header("Location: $url");
 }
 
 public function logout()
 {
  session_destroy();
  $_SESSION['userSession'] = false;
 }
 
 function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
 {      
  require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP(); 
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;                     
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
  $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
  $mail->Port       = 465;             
  $mail->AddAddress($email);
  $mail->Username="tvojlink@gmail.com";  
  $mail->Password="*******************";            
  $mail->SetFrom('tvojlink@gmail.com','noreply');
  $mail->AddReplyTo("tvojlink@gmail.com","Podpora");
  $mail->Subject    = $subject;
  $mail->MsgHTML($message);
  $mail->Send();
 } 
}
```

Comment: What happened when you followed the directions in line 3 of your error message? Many hosts wont accept mail sent from your localhost - yahoo being a notable example. The code appears to succeed, but the email is ultimately rejected because there isn't an MX record for your localhost. However, this appears not to be the case here - the error message says the password is not accepted and that you should goto: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754

Comment: @enhzflep okey now it's working thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, glad its working for you now. :)